# Cannot uninstall Anaconda via any installer

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I cannot uninstall Ananconda due to this error:
[image: Here]

Suddenly, today, my Ananconda stopped working and I followed all steps in the troubleshooting manual to uninstall and reinstall but its my 7th install and yet I have nothing.

I tried the latest installer and that screenshot is [image: here]

So here are my questions:

1. How will I uninstall this?
2. My anaconda navigator does not pop up from the start and I could not find anaconda prompt anywhere to try anything else. I got an error while trying to do conda remove and install it back again( the navigator ) but no luck. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?
3. It used to work before without a PYTHONPATH variable. Should I add that to try to make this work?
   Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my Anaconda? Please.

Comment: I did a lot of installing and uninstalling of Miniconda3 recently and the official uninstall broke my Windows Command Prompt actually. Could you should the output of your PATH variable at the current state and I assume you are using Windows 10?

Comment: One more question: Did you do a system-wide installation or a user installation?

Comment: I did a user installation.

Comment: I changed TEMP and TMP env according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789886/error-failed-to-create-temp-directory-c-users-user-appdata-local-temp-conda

Comment: And removed the Anaconda elements from the PATH variable.I have literally tried everything. Now there is another problem. I cant delete conda_temp with a file called "CMcUploader". Its a log file. And its sitting in my C drive. I'm at my wits end with this :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running uninstall-anaconda3 with administrator privileges?
I see that your anaconda3 installation is in C:\Anaconda and so you probably launched the installation with administrative privileges.
If you are successful in uninstalling, I suggest you then redo the installation by choosing your home directory (usually C:\users<your_name>) and as a user with normal privileges.
Finally, the fact that anaconda-navigator suddenly stopped working could depend on PyQt5: it happened to me several times and I always solved it by removing the package:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
```