# Failed to create a temporary directory when running python prompt

Tags: python, directory, anaconda, temporary

I am trying to set up Geopandas but I am having a fair few problems.

I am using anaconda and I have created a new environment called geo_env in Anaconda that can be seen below, but every time I try and activate the environment to follow the process. How do I activate the environment?

```
C:\Users\Alex Markides>conda env list

conda environments:
base                  *  C:\Users\Alex Markides\anaconda4
geo_env                  C:\Users\Alex Markides\anaconda4\envs\geo_env
my37env                  C:\Users\Alex Markides\anaconda4\envs\my37env

C:\Users\Alex Markides>activate geo_env
Failed to create temp directory "C:\Users\Alex Markides\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-<RANDOM>\"
```

I have also installed python 2.7 in this environ

Comment: Seems like it has already an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692786/13679903

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : Failed to create temp directory "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-<RANDOM>\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789886/error-failed-to-create-temp-directory-c-users-user-appdata-local-temp-conda)